# In Springmvc and Thymeleaf, getting "Cannot initialize template resolver: a resource resolver has not been set]" error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I will show some mistakes next, but first I will explain it. According to some of my output, creating ViewResolver, SpringTemplateEngine, TemplateResolver bean is no problem, and then found the home page, view name is "home", here is no problem.

And then, according the thymeleaf template, I'll get the path "/WEB-INF/templates/home.html" . But it's wrong here. The following error occurred

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Spittr] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot initialize template resolver: a resource resolver has not been set] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot initialize template resolver: a resource resolver has not been set
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver.initializeSpecific(TemplateResolver.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractTemplateResolver.initialize(AbstractTemplateResolver.java:106)
    at org.thymeleaf.Configuration.initialize(Configuration.java:200)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.initialize(TemplateEngine.java:831)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1122)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1095)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:259)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I do not know what it means, and check a lot but do not know how to solve. I will show some bean:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    System.out.println("create:viewResolver");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver){
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    System.out.println("create:templateEngine");
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new TemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    System.out.println("create:templateResolver");
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Following is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("control:home");
        return "home";        //view name：home
    }
}}
```

Please help me look at the above questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you provide, no resolver is set on the templateEngine. Do not pass in the `templateResolver` as argument but just create new instance inside the Bean method like below:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    System.out.println("create:viewResolver");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    System.out.println("create:templateEngine");
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    System.out.println("create:templateResolver");
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: First thank you for answering my question.I modified the configuration according to your suggestion.But still have the same problems as before.Is there anything else that could go wrong?

Comment: @yjl , I updated the answer modified your `templateResolver()` method with `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver `. Or if you are using thymeleaf 3, you can also try the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`. Let me know whether it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new TemplateResolver(); // This line
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    System.out.println("create:templateResolver");
    return templateResolver;
}
```

to

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    System.out.println("create:templateResolver");
    return templateResolver;
}
```